# What's the default size of AES generated keys?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

In the code

```
javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();
```

What's the size of the generated key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure there is specification for the default size but the Sun JCE generates 16 bytes (128-bit) keys.

You can find out by checking the encoded size,

```
  int keyBits = (key.getEncoded()).length * 8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you simply call the method `getEncoded()` on the returned key, then check the length?

Or, you could call the method `init()` on the KeyGenerator with parameters of either 128, 192, or 256 bits to be sure.

Or, you could compare the returned key from the no-length version of the call with ones where the length was explicitly set (using the `init()` method) and see which one matches.